# How can I test fluffyblocks?

Tags: source, compile, compact-blocks

How can I test [Fluffyblocks](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2633/what-are-fluffy-blocks) on mainnet? I found this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ac0rnsoup/monero/tree/v0.10.3.1fluffy) linked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6dords/help_test_fluffyblocks_compact_blocks_whatever/di66ise/) but I am unsure how to use it in production.

Can I compile this source code to work with my existing blockchain or will I need to sync from scratch?

What types of bug or behaviors should I be looking for while testing it?

Comment: Coordinated test ongoing, you could join in: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6eef96/fluffynet_update_please_move_some_to_tier_3_4_and/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good that you ask. Actually, a
coordinated test is ongoing and you could join in: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6eef96/fluffynet_update_please_move_some_to_tier_3_4_and/

And yes, you can use existing blockchain, the change is in networking part so interest is in blocks / TX propagation etc.